# General Error SQLSTATE[HY000] when executing Query in Yii 2

Tags: yii, yii2

Here's my code:

```
$sql = "
        SET @run_balqty :=0;

        SELECT 
            transaction_date, 
            item_id, 
            item_description, 
            unit_id, 
            quantity,
            ( @run_balqty := @run_balqty + quantity ) AS balance_qty,
            reference_code
        FROM 
            `report_ledger` AS ledger
        WHERE
            item_id = 3147
        ORDER BY
            transaction_date ";

$query = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

When I tried to run this code. I get this **error**.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

**Now.. My question is: Why Do I get this error? and how can I make it run?**

Need Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are trying to fetch the results of a query that contains a command (`SET @run_balqty :=0`) that it is not 'fetchable'. You have to execute first that command alone, and then you can call `queryAll()` to your `SELECT` query command:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SET @run_balqty :=null;")->execute();

$sql = "
        SELECT 
            transaction_date, 
            item_id, 
            item_description, 
            unit_id, 
            quantity,
            ( @run_balqty := @run_balqty + quantity ) AS balance_qty,
            reference_code
        FROM 
            `report_ledger` AS ledger
        WHERE
            item_id = 3147
        ORDER BY
            transaction_date ";

$query = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

P.S.: Be careful using the `SET` statement, read [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/3796).